# Set up nginx to proxy web and ssh by domain?

Tags: ssh, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm not a pro with nginx. Please bear with me. I couldn't find a working how-to anywhere in the net. Only old stuff with nginx versions not able to pre-read anything. So this is my last resort, kind of.

I want to connect to some servers by http/https and ssh through nginx via subdomains from outside.

- [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) -> 192.168.1.1:443
- ssh ssh2.mydomain.com -> 192.168.1.2:22
- ssh ssh3.mydomain.com -> 192.168.1.3:22

The ssh ports can differ. No need to stick to 22. I think this must be possible with `ssl_preread on` and upstreams? How should the nginx configuration look like? Does the ssh command need anything to pre-send the subdomain name?